# how to send message from service to activity

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, message

I build an AsyncTask that create a service and now I want to sent from service to AsyncTask message.
my code on the AsyncTask is:

```
  class ResponseHandler extends Handler {
  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "message from service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

hope that it  will handle the message from service correct my if I wrong.

and from service tried to do this

```
     Message message = Message.obtain(null, MyService.ADD_RESPONSE_HANDLER);
     message.replyTo = messenger;
      try {
             myService.send(message);
             catch (RemoteException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

but my errors are cannot find symbol  in lines:

```
 MyService.ADD_RESPONSE_HANDLER
  message.replyTo = messenger;
  try {
  myService.send(message);
```

What do I need to add? Please give me a code that will do the work. thanks a lot.

Comment: Any reason you have not marked any answers ? Did you try both, which answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 7):

One way is using `ResultReceiver`. Here is my complete blog post which I had recently posted with an Example.

[`How to update Activity from Service using ResultReceiver`](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html)

Answer (score 4):

For sending a message or any data from service to Activity you will need to Register an **Custom Broadcast receiver**.see these tutorials  for sending data from service to Activity:

[Communication between service and activity – Part 1](http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/)

[Custom Intents and Broadcasting with Receivers](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)